# C++ array issue long line

Tags: c++, arrays

The code inside int main it doesn't break so it out puts a 8x8 array with 5x5 squares in it it just puts it on a long line im pretty new to c++ so please help me understand it.

```
char ruta[8][8];
for (int a = 0; a < 8; a++)  {
    for (int b = 0; b < 8; b++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
                if (x == 0 || x == 4 || y == 4 || y == 0) {
                    ruta[x][y] = 'a';
                }
                else {
                    ruta[x][y] = ' ';
                }

                ruta[2][2] = 'x';
                cout << ruta[x][y];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
```

Comment: This may a good moment to take a time and [learn to use debugger](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Knowing how you can go step-by-step with your code will help you immensely with all programming.

Comment: Not sure you want your loop for `a`/`b`, as these variable are not used.

Comment: You should add more empty lines, it improves performance. (sarcasm)

Comment: @YSC if there are too many blank lines in a row its better for performance if you jump over them with `goto`

Comment: Works for me, it correctly prints the 5x5 box. A lot of it, presumably 64 times. What's the exact output that you're getting?

Comment: well i want it to print out the 5x5 box in 8 rows and 8 colums so 64 boxes with 5x5 box in them not in a long line

Comment: For that you need to change the order in which you do things. For instance, the first row of your ouput is going to be the first row of the 5x5 grid... repeated 8 times. So so render your 5x5 grid but with each row repeated 8 times, and then you repeat that result 8 times.

Comment: You might want to iterate over the complete grid and use the `operator %` to decide what the edges and center are, in which case your array would have to be `grid[8*5][8*5]`. The grid can be filled in first and printed out afterwards so you can actually do interesting things with it.

Answer (score 1):

So, I'll explain what is happening in your code. As the innermost loop (i.e loop with **'x'**) runs 5 times which is responsible for putting out the data five times in a single line(i.e., 5 rows). The next for loop(i.e., loop with **'y'**) is basically making it look like a 5x5 array (i.e., responsible for printing 5 columns). And the outer loops which use **'a'** and **'b'** basically are making it run for 8x8 i.e., 64 times. You have initialized **ruta** to be 8x8, but you are using only 4x4 of it (i.e., from 0,0 to 3,3). The rest i.e., from 4,0 to 7,7 are not being used. Cheers!

PS: Can you please explain why you used system("PAUSE"), are you using any IDE, where you should see logs to look at the output?

Comment: Well It's because our teacher said we need it so other wise it would just return 0 and the program would close itself

Comment: Are you using Windows to run this program? It's just a simple hack to stop the terminal from closing. It is avoided as we may not need the application to stay open. You can see the result in the terminal in most cases like when you are running the program from terminal in linux-based machines.

Comment: well we are using visual studio so yes windows

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like that:

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr const char* lines[] = {
 "aaaaa",
 "a   a",
 "a x a",
 "a   a",
 "aaaaa"
};

int main()
{
    constexpr int Row = 3;
    constexpr int Col = 2;
    for (int j = 0; j != Row; ++j) {
        for (auto line : lines) {
            for (int i = 0; i != Col; ++i) {
                std::cout << line << " ";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/2iykme)

With output:

```
aaaaa aaaaa 
a   a a   a 
a x a a x a 
a   a a   a 
aaaaa aaaaa 
aaaaa aaaaa 
a   a a   a 
a x a a x a 
a   a a   a 
aaaaa aaaaa 
aaaaa aaaaa 
a   a a   a 
a x a a x a 
a   a a   a 
aaaaa aaaaa
```

Comment: thank you! So if i would want to make it 8x8 board i'd change row to 8 and col to 8?

Comment: @SavannPojken: yes.

Answer (score 0):

Let's examine your code.

As you can see, your code snippet has four nested loops. The outermost loop(with variable 'a') iterates the for loop for each of the row of your 2D array. The second loop(with variable 'b') iterates the for loop for each of the column of your 2D array.
Basically, these two loops cover every element of your 2D array.
The remaining two loops (with iterators ''x' and 'y'), do the same thing, but only for first 5 rows( row 0 to row 4) and first 5 columns (column 0 to column 4), i.e., the first 25 elements.

The inner two loops initialise your elements with 'a' if they occur in the first row( row 0), fifth row(row 4), first column(column 0) or fifth column(column 4).
The statement :

> ruta[2][2] = 'x';

initialises your element at ruta[2][2] with x.

The cout statement is placed inside the innermost loop, therefore, it is executed as many times as the innermost loop is executed, i.e. 25 times (for the first 25 elements).
Therefore you will get a matrix of 5 rows and 5 columns as output.

I hope this helps.